# PyDev console does not accept ANY input

Tags: jython, pydev

I'm wondering if anybody can help figure this out... I am running JRE/JDK 7u9 32-bit with Eclipse 4.2.1, and PyDev 2.7.1 (everything is up to date). I've got Jython 2.5.3 installed, and have PyDev set to use it as the interpreter.

My issue is that for some reason, the console in PyDev won't seem to register ANY input.

For example, I have the following code:

```
inStr = raw_input('Enter a word: ').strip()
print inStr
```

When I run this, the console does display the "enter a word" prompt. However, when I type anything in the console and press enter, it just moves to a new line, NO additional output of any kind is produced, and the program keeps running, waiting to receive input. I've tried Java 6 and different versions of Jython, but nothing I do makes any difference. I've read about the PyDev console sometimes inputting additional hidden characters and as a result, causing unexpected program behavior, but I thought the .strip() takes care of that. In my case, it's as though the console is just not accepting any input period....

Answer (score 0):

I would've put this as a comment to your question, but maybe I don't have sufficient privileges.

I had the same problems (initially, I thought it was working on Eclipse 3.6). I ran your code (without the strip()) successfully (i.e., I entered input and it printed to the console) in the following configurations:

Eclipse 3.6.1/Python 2.6.6

Eclipse 4.2.1/Python 2.6.6

With the interactive console, it worked on:

Eclipse 3.6.1/Jython 2.5.3

Eclipse 4.2.1/Jython 2.5.3

It unfortunately failed for

Eclipse 3.6.1/Jython 2.5.3

Eclipse 4.2.1/Jython 2.5.3

Answer (score 0):

Just to make it clear for anyone that stumbles upon this, this is an issue on Jython 2.5.3.

If you go to Jython 2.5.2 or Jython 2.5.4rc1, things work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. After clicking the red square in the top of the console to terminate the console tooltip, it stopped.